# How to solve $at + b = 0 \pmod {(a-t)}$?

Tags: natural-numbers

Is there any way (except trying for $t=0,1,2,\ldots,a-1)$ to solve the following equation for $t$ when $a$ and $b$ are known?

$$ at +b = 0 \pmod{(a-t)} \text{ with } a,b,t \in N $$

Comment: Do you want to find one solution? Then take $t = a-1$, or do you want to find all?

Answer (score 3):

$at +b = 0 \mod\ (a-t)$ then $at+b=-a^2+at \mod\ (a-t)$ we have $$b+a^2=0 \mod\ (a-t)$$ and $$b+a^2=k(t-a)$$ $$t=\frac{b}{k}+\frac{a^2}{k}+a: k\in \mathbb Zk|b ,k|a^2$$

Comment: How did you get the first implication? Did you just put $-a(a-t)$?

Comment: @Igor:yes if $a=b \mod p$ then we have  $a=b+mk \mod m$

Comment: How do you get $k|b ,k|a^2$? Doesn't it rather have to be $k|(b+a^2)$?

Comment: Nice Maisam. +1

Comment: @Babak S.:thanks

Comment: Still, could someone answer my question? How do you get $k|b,k|a^2$, and shouldn't it be $k|(b+a^2)$ instead?

Answer (score 0):

$$a*t +b = 0 \mod (a-t) \Leftrightarrow at +b = k(a-t)$$
for some integer $k$.

This is equivalent to

$$at+kt=ka-b \Leftrightarrow t=\frac{ka-b}{a+k}=a-\frac{a^2+b}{a+k}$$

This is an integer if and only if $a+k$ is a divisor of $a^2+b$.

Thus,

**Step 1:** List all the **integer** divisors of $a^2+b$.

**Step 2:** For each divisor $d$ set $k=d-a$ and then $t=a-\frac{a^2+b}{d}$. Keep only the positive solutions.

Comment: Shouldn't you actually get $at+kt=ka-b$ instead of $at+kt=ka+b$?

Comment: @valgel Fixed. I think...